# En linux ¿un archivo o directorio puede pertenecer a mas de un grupo?

Tags: linux, permisos

Soy principiante en Linux, y me surgió esta duda:

- ¿puede un archivo o directorio pertenecer a mas de un grupo?

Comment: Para quienes piensen en votar para cerrar la pregunta, les adelanto que esta es una pregunta válida para el sitio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, un archivo o directorio solo puede pertenecer a un grupo.

Pero es posible dar permisos a más de un grupo usando access control lists. Su uso está descrito en su [manpage en inglés](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/acl.5.html).

Comment: Entiendo, te agradezco tu respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El propietario solo es uno, luego le daras permisos a grupos o usuarios para trabajar con ellos.